# No audio from streaming MP4 video using VLC over http

Tags: audio, video, video-streaming, vlc, libvlc

I try to stream my video file using VLC player. I choose http transfer protocol and MP4 encoder (H.264 + MP3(MP4)). And automatically I get next command line presets:

> :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/} :sout-all :sout-keep

Streaming is works great but no audio sound. 
I launched it on my PC localhost and local networks on Windows, and I have no 
results.If I change encoder to H.264 + MP3 TS:

> :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ts,dst=:9000/}

If I change transfer protocol to RTSP(or RTP), the sound starts to play with any types of encoders. F.e:

> :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=auto,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:9000/test} :sout-all :sout-keep

Why sound does't play whith encoder (H.264 + MP3(MP4))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Streaming is works great but no audio sound...

Try using `acodec=mp3` or `acodec=aac` since they're supported formats for FLV containers.

*example:*

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/} :sout-all :sout-keep
```